# geeglm: Does as.factor() not work with corstr=fixed?

Tags: clustered-standard-errors, robust-standard-error, geepack

(See "Edits" at the bottom for partial resolution.)

I am interested in generating point estimates for each cluster in my data using geeglm.

However, when I use as.factor() over the predictor variable (and don't fit an intercept), the standard error estimates are all equal to 0.

This also occurs for the example provided in the fixed2Zcor documentation. I'll use that example to illustrate the problem. The setup of that example goes as follows:

```
tvar      <- timeorder + rnorm(length(timeorder))
idvar <- rep(1:6, each=5)
uuu   <- rep(rnorm(6), each=5)
yvar  <- 1 + 2*tvar + uuu + rnorm(length(tvar))
simdat <- data.frame(idvar, timeorder, tvar, yvar)
head(simdat,12)

simdatPerm <- simdat[sample(nrow(simdat)),]
simdatPerm <- simdatPerm[order(simdatPerm$idvar),]
head(simdatPerm)

cor.fixed <- matrix(c(1    , 0.5  , 0.25,  0.125, 0.125,
                      0.5  , 1    , 0.25,  0.125, 0.125,
                      0.25 , 0.25 , 1   ,  0.5  , 0.125,
                      0.125, 0.125, 0.5  , 1    , 0.125,
                      0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 1     ), nrow=5, ncol=5)

zcor <- fixed2Zcor(cor.fixed, id=simdatPerm$idvar, waves=simdatPerm$timeorder)
```

When one fits the following geeglm model, standard error estimates are generated:

```
mod4 <- geeglm(yvar~tvar, id=idvar, data=simdatPerm, corstr="fixed", zcor=zcor)

summary(mod4)

Call:
geeglm(formula = yvar ~ tvar, data = simdatPerm, id = idvar, 
    zcor = zcor, corstr = "fixed")

 Coefficients:
            Estimate Std.err Wald Pr(>|W|)    
(Intercept)   0.6996  0.4952    2     0.16    
tvar          2.0489  0.0782  686   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, when one treats "tvar" as a factor, all of the standard error estimates are 0. See below:

```
mod5 <- geeglm(yvar~as.factor(tvar)-1, id=idvar, data=simdatPerm, corstr="fixed", zcor=zcor)

summary(mod5)

Call:
geeglm(formula = yvar ~ as.factor(tvar) - 1, data = simdatPerm, 
    id = idvar, zcor = zcor, corstr = "fixed")

 Coefficients:
                                                       Estimate Std.err Wald Pr(>|W|)    
as.factor(tvar)-0.521913097120162    -1.85    0.00  Inf   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(tvar)-0.336747442280109    -1.64    0.00  Inf   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(tvar)-0.202770320273852     1.47    0.00  Inf   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(tvar)1.07128399555566       3.16    0.00  Inf   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(tvar)1.40302727579937       3.67    0.00  Inf   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(tvar)1.40535644869792       2.54    0.00  Inf   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(tvar)1.87374961826701       7.28    0.00  Inf   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(tvar)1.96689050105388       5.22    0.00  Inf   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(tvar)2.06885855689724       5.15    0.00  Inf   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(tvar)2.21300704174418       5.39    0.00  Inf   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(tvar)2.63119744869911       7.06    0.00  Inf   <2e-16 ***
(rest of output left out)
```

I am hoping you could shed some light on why this is.

Many thanks for any help.

EDITS

This is in part a follow up to @David's useful suggestion. Thank you, David, for your response.

It appears the issue I had was not due to the sample size. Rather, there was one cohort for which all of the individuals had perfectly correlated measurements—i.e., each individual was either "1,1" or "0,0" for the two (binary) measurements we have for them. This meant the correlation estimate for that cohort was equal to 1.

Why was this an issue? I want to run a geeglm model in which there are fixed, cohort-specific correlation estimates. I have (attempted) to do this by creating a zcor vector myself. (The fixed2Zcor() function is not suited for this task.) For instance, suppose there are just two cohorts, and that the first cohort has five members and that the second has three. Stipulate that the cohort-specific correlation estimate for the first cohort is .4 and that for the second cohort it is .7. The zcor vector should (I believe) look like this: c(.4,.4,.4,.4,.4,.7,.7,.7). Why? Since there are just two measurements, the correlation matrix has one value in its lower triangle—.4 in the case of the first cohort, and .7 in the case of the second cohort. In turn, .4 gets repeated five times in the zcor vector because there are five members in the first cohort, while .7 gets repeated three times because the second cohort has three members.

Now turn to my actual data. The issue I was running into is that, because the correlation estimate of one of my cohorts was 1, this created in the zcor vector a string of 1s of size n, where n is the number of individuals in that cohort. This threw a wrench into the mathematical machinery. Changing the correlation estimate from 1 to .99 resolved the issue, for what it's worth.

Comment: Why do you want to treat a numeric variable as factor?

Comment: @dipetkov: This was merely because I was recycling the example from the fixed2Zcor documentation. The predictor variable I have is integer valued.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, `tvar` has a unique value for each response (because of the normal random noise). Using `as.factor()` on it makes a factor variable with $n$ levels. Therefore, using `~as.factor(tvar)` creates a saturated predictor matrix, where the fitted values are exactly equal to the response values. Depending on the particular software implementation this may result in an error, or in this case it gives all standard errors as 0.

Perhaps your situation also is using `as.factor()` on continuous data? In that case you'd probably be better off manually creating the factor variable. The `dplyr` function, `case_when()`, can be useful for that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand your point about as.factor(tvar). However, in my case, I am using as.factor() over a vector that is not continuous—the year within which subjects were born.

Comment: @BrianM. Without knowing more about your data it's hard to say. If you have years where only 1 individual was born, or years where the combination of year with other covariates can uniquely identify individuals, then you might still have this issue. I'd still recommend trying to create the factor variable manually, perhaps by grouping into 5-year ranges? If you're sure you should have a large enough sample, maybe try as.factor(round(tvar)), which resolves the issue for the example data.